# 3 Moshiachs in Midrash Rabbah?

Tags: midrash, messiah, shevatim-12-tribes

We all know, that besides for the main Moshiach - Moshiach Ben Dovid (from Yehudah), who will fight Hashem’s wars, gather the scattered Jews and build the Beis Hamikdosh - there is another Moshiach - Moshiach Ben Yosef (from Efrayim), who will come before him to fight Gog and Magog, and Amolek.

However, recently I came across a passage in Bamidbar Rabbah 14:1, where it says as follows:

״ולי מנשה״ - זה משיח, שעומד מבניו של מנשה; ״ואפרים מעוז ראשי״ - זה משוח מלחמה, שבא  מאפרים; ״יהודה מחוקקי״ - זה הגואל הגדול, שבא מבני בניו של דויד.

Which implies that there are actually 3 Moshiachs - from Menashe, from Efrayim and from Dovid (Yehudah).

Now my question is: what is the purpose of this משיח -
The only source I know of, regarding the connection of the tribe of Menashe with the Geulah, is from the “Bnei Yissoschor” on the month of “Marcheshvan”, where he says that the ״חנוכה״ - dedication - of the Beis Hamikdosh will take place in the month of “Marcheshvan”, which corresponds to the tribe of Menashe - does that have anything to do with this Midrash?

Comment: "why is he not spoken about?" relevant Rambam: כל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן--לא יידע אדם היאך יהיו, עד שיהיו:  שדברים סתומים הן אצל הנביאים.  גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו, אלא לפי הכרע הפסוקים; ולפיכך יש להם מחלוקת בדברים אלו.  ועל כל פנים, אין סידור הוויית דברים אלו ולא דקדוקן, עיקר בדת.   ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות, ולא יאריך בדברי מדרשות האמורים בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן; ולא ישימם עיקר--שאינן מביאין לא לידי אהבה, ולא לידי יראה

Comment: Translation: All these and similar matters, however, man will not know how they will occur until they come to pass; for in the [statements of the] prophets these are undefined matters, and the sages, too, do not have a clear tradition on these subjects except for the [apparent] implications of the Scriptural verses. That is why they have differences of opinion in these matters. In any case, neither the sequence of these events nor their details are fundamental to the faith.

Comment: cont.: A person should not involve himself with the homiletical statements or protract on the Midrashim speaking of these or similar matters, nor is one to consider them fundamental; for they do not lead to either fear or love [of G‑d]

Answer (score 1):

Bamidbar [Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.14.1?lang=bi&with=Yefeh%20To%27ar&lang2=en) 14 is identifying all sorts of people as those who have been part of the salvation of Israel

The section reads

> דבר אחר, לי גלעד ולי מנשה, לפי שיש מחלוקת הרבה על המשוחים, יש אומרים ז', שנאמר (מיכה ה') והקמנו עליו שבעה רועים, ויש אומרים ח', שנאמר (שם) ושמנה נסיכי אדם, ואינו אלא מה שמפורש ד', שנאמר (זכריה ב') ויראני ה' ארבעה חרשים ואומר מה אלה באים לעשות, ויאמר לאמר אלה הקרנות אשר זרו וגו', ואלו הן ד' חרשים דוד בא ומפרש, לי גלעד, זה אליהו שהיה מתושבי גלעד, לי מנשה, זה משיח שעומד מבניו של מנשה, שנאמר (תהלים פ') לפני אפרים ובנימין ומנשה וגו', ואפרים מעוז ראשי זה משוח מלחמה שבא מאפרים, שנאמר בכור שורו הדר לו, יהודה מחוקקי זה הגואל הגדול שהוא מבני בניו של דוד

among the 7 or 8, one is listed as being from Menashe.

The Yefeh Toah identifies this with Machir Ben Menashe

> לי מנשה זה משיח שעומד מבניו של מנשה. ונ"ל המלקט שזה הוא פירוש המדרש לא יסור שבט מיהודה זה מכיר בן מנשה וע"ז מסיים בב"ר בפ' ויחי עד כי יבא שילה זה מלך בן דוד ויסור תלונת המ"כ עד שדחק עצמו לעיל בב"ר ורוצה לגרוס גירסא אחרת וז"ל ולבי אומר לי זה מפיבושת דכתיב ויקחהו מבית מכיר וגו' והכוונה שלא יכרית זרע מלכות שאול אף שיהודה ימלוך ונקרא מחוקק לפי שהיה ת"ח גדול כמ"ש בפ"ק דברכות שהיה מבייש פני דוד בהלכה וק"ל

Comment: So you prefer his reading as a reference to Mefiboshet?